# django many to one in models

Tags: python, django, django-models

in this code i want to create a new model in this new model every area from ***Area*** has more than one city from ***Cities***

how to do that

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.area)


class Cities(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.city)
```

Comment: [This](https://www.revsys.com/tidbits/tips-using-djangos-manytomanyfield/) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ForeignKey` for many-to-one relationships.

For exapmle, like this.

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.area)


class Cities(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.city)
```

See [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) for detail